# How to resolve error "Rowtime timestamp is null" in flink server

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to run some code in flink server but unable to

Below is my code

```
    DataStream<UserInfo> keyedStream = executionEnvironment
                .addSource(new UserDataSource());

        keyedStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MessageWaterEmitter());

        tableEnv.registerDataStream("test", keyedStream, "userId,ticks,startime.rowtime");

        Table table = tableEnv
                .sqlQuery(
                        "SELECT userId,COUNT(userId) as ticks,TUMBLE_END(startime,INTERVAL '5' SECOND) as startime FROM test "
                                + "GROUP BY TUMBLE(startime,INTERVAL '5' SECOND),userId");

        DataStream<Row> userInfoDataStream = tableEnv.toRetractStream(table, Row.class)
                .filter(new FilterFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, Row>>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(Tuple2<Boolean, Row> booleanUserInfoTuple2) throws Exception {
                        return booleanUserInfoTuple2.f0;
                    }
                }).map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, Row>, Row>() {
                    @Override
                    public Row map(Tuple2<Boolean, Row> booleanUserInfoTuple2) throws Exception {
                        return booleanUserInfoTuple2.f1;
                    }
                });

        JdbcSink sink = new JdbcSink();
        userInfoDataStream.addSink(sink);
```

Below is the error am getting

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Rowtime timestamp is null. Please make sure that a proper TimestampAssigner is defined and the stream environment uses the EventTime time characteristic.
    at DataStreamSourceConversion$651.processElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.CRowOutputProcessRunner.processElement(CRowOutputProcessRunner.scala:70)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.processElement(ProcessOperator.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:637)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:612)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:592)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:707)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:660)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:727)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$ManualWatermarkContext.processAndCollect(StreamSourceContexts.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$WatermarkContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:394)
    at flink.source.UserDataSource.run(UserDataSource.java:20)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:208)
```

can any body help me with this problem? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is that while you are calling `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on `keyedStream`, you aren't doing anything with the result of this call. If you rework the code like this, it will work:

```java
DataStream<UserInfo> keyedStream = executionEnvironment
    .addSource(new UserDataSource())
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MessageWaterEmitter());

tableEnv.registerDataStream("test", keyedStream, "userId,ticks,startime.rowtime");
```

Calling `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on a stream doesn't modify that stream, but instead returns a new stream that has timestamps and watermarks.

This could also be fixed this like, which might be a bit clearer as to what is going on:

```java
DataStream<UserInfo> streamWithTSandWMs = keyedStream
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MessageWaterEmitter());

tableEnv.registerDataStream("test", streamWithTSandWMs, "userId,ticks,startime.rowtime");
```